# Cordova 1.7 - Media, playing sound clips, crashes after several plays - Android

Tags: android, cordova

Im using Media like this:

```
var my_media = new Media(src);
my_media.play()
```

Most sound clips are really short, like 2-3 seconds. I play back a sound when the user clicks the play sound buttons. If I keep pressing play continuasly the Mediaplayer crashes or something, the sound stops playing and in Eclips its says this:
**Unable to create media player.**

The app still works, but all the sound in the app stops playing.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly use

```
var my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
my_media.play();


 // onSuccess Callback
        function onSuccess() {
            my_media.release();
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

 // onError Callback 
        function onError(error) {
            console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
```

The Main Highlight point is that use "my_media.release();" in onSuccess callback

REF: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.release

Comment: Yes, @Varun has it exactly right. The Android OS only has a limited amount of Audio resources which it can hold on to at any one time. The upper limit on my device is 7. If you are done with a sound you'll need to release the audio resource back to the OS.